# dimple js line and bubble chart overlaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, data-visualization, dimple.js

I have some points of bubble and line charts that overlap at few points on chart. However, overlap hides another point making the visuals confusion. Any one can fix this jsfiddle so on hover at overlap points shows on tooltip both points values. Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d54vY/

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);

    // The default data set for these examples has regular times
    // and the point of this demo is to show the time axis
    // functionality, therefore a small bespoke data set is used.
    data = [
      { "Shift":"2012","Date":"12 Jul 2010 10:00","Value":1000 },
      { "Shift":"2012","Date":"20 Jul 2010 10:20","Value":1200 },
      { "Shift":"2012","Date":"1 Aug 2010 10:00","Value":1600 },
      { "Shift":"2012","Date":"8 Aug 2010 10:00","Value":1700 },
      { "Shift":"2013","Date":"12 Jul 2010 10:00","Value":2400 },
      { "Shift":"2013","Date":"20 Jul 2010 10:00","Value":2000 },
      { "Shift":"2013","Date":"1 Aug 2010 10:00","Value":1600 },
      { "Shift":"2013","Date":"8 Aug 2010 10:00","Value":1700 },
    ];

    // Create Separate Date and Time, this allows us to draw them
    // on separate axes.  Despite the time axis only displaying
    // the time portion, the whole date is used so they need to
    // have the same date allocated
    data.forEach(function (d) {
        d["Day"] = d["Date"].substring(0, d["Date"].length - 6);
        d["Time of Day"] =
            "2000-01-01 " + d["Date"].substring(d["Date"].length - 5);
    }, this);

    // Create the chart as usual
    var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
    myChart.setBounds(70, 40, 490, 320)

    // Add the x axis reading dates in the format 01 Jan 2012
    // and displaying them 01 Jan
    var x = myChart.addTimeAxis("x", "Day", "%d %b %Y", "%d %b");

    // Add the y axis reading dates and times but only outputting
    // times.  
    //var y = myChart.addTimeAxis("y", "Time of Day",
    //    "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", "%H:%M");

    var y = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Value");
    // Size the bubbles by volume
    var z = myChart.addMeasureAxis("z", "Value");

    // Setting min and max dates requires them to be set
    // as actual javascript date objects
    x.overrideMin = new Date("2010-06-20");
    x.overrideMax = new Date("2011-01-02");
    //y.overrideMin = new Date("01/01/2000 9:00 am");
    //y.overrideMax = new Date("01/01/2000 6:00 pm");

    // Show a label for every 4 weeks.
    x.timePeriod = d3.time.weeks;
    x.timeInterval = 4;

    // Control bubble sizes by setting the max and min values    
    z.overrideMin = 900;
    z.overrideMax = 3000;

    // Add the bubble series for shift values first so that it is
    // drawn behind the lines
    myChart.addSeries("Shift", dimple.plot.bubble);

    // Add the line series on top of the bubbles.  The bubbles
    // and line points will naturally fall in the same places
    var s = myChart.addSeries("Shift", dimple.plot.line);

    // Add line markers to the line because it looks nice
    s.lineMarkers = true;

    // Show a legend
    myChart.addLegend(180, 10, 360, 20, "right");

    // Draw everything
    myChart.draw();
```

Comment: Sorry, but why is it confusing if the dashed lines tell you exactly which point is being hovered over? Are you referring to some other much more severe overlap that is not part of the example you linked us to?

Comment: { "Shift":"2012","Date":"1 Aug 2010 10:00","Value":1600 } and { "Shift":"2013","Date":"1 Aug 2010 10:00","Value":1600 }. On hover tooltip only shows the value of 2012 because 2013 is under it. It would be nice if the tooltip on hover shows the shift: 2012 and 2013 for overlapping points. This was my point.

Comment: I see now...the data is completely overlapping one another. The graph looked so nice and clean that I overlooked checking the data.